# Normal map from displacement map

Tags: .net, vb.net, 3d, drawing, imagefilter

I would like to create a normal map from a displacement map. 
This function is available in 3D applications like Blender, but I would like to do that programatically using `VB.NET`, however I don't have any knowledge about it.

There was a link to the basic approach [here](http://blog.archetype-inc.com/post/141158780/bump-mapping-with-silverlight-3), however it's gone.
Perhaps there is even an imagefilter to do that in `.NET`.
I'd be glad if anybody with some experience about it could help me here.

Comment: [_**~ Magic! ~**_](http://web.archive.org/web/20100126043830/http://blog.archetype-inc.com/post/141158780/bump-mapping-with-silverlight-3)

Comment: Apart from the archived link above, this was the best thing I could find: https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/475213-generate-normal-map-from-heightmap-algorithm/

Comment: Oh, ok, it involves some heavy math. I was hoping it would be like System.Drawing.MagicallyCreateANormalMap :-)

Comment: Nah, there's no built in stuff for this. `System.Drawing` only includes basic methods for regular image manipulation (drawing, color translation, image translation, etc.).